# How to specify dependencies in qt_add_qml_module (CMake for Qt 6.2)

Tags: qt, cmake, dependencies, qt6

When using `qt_add_qml_module` to specify a QML module, how do you handle Qt modules that it depends on (e.g. QtMultimedia)?

---

If I have class `Synthesizer` that extends QML, but which has no dependencies, the following works fine:

```
qt_add_qml_module(Synth
    URI Synth
    VERSION 1.0
    SOURCES
        Synthesizer.h Synthesizer.cpp
)

target_include_directories(Synthplugin
     PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

target_link_libraries(myapp
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
    Synth
)
```

However if `Synthesizer` uses QtMultimedia classes, then this is insufficient, and results in errors like:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "QAudioSink::start()", referenced from:
      Synthesizer::start() in Synthesizer.cpp.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have a tried and tested approach, based on putting each QML module into its own library.

First create the library within subfolder `Synth`:

```
qt_add_library(SynthLib STATIC)

qt_add_qml_module(SynthLib
    URI Synth
    VERSION 1.0
    SOURCES
        Synthesizer.h Synthesizer.cpp
)

target_include_directories(SynthLib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(SynthLib
    PUBLIC Qt6::Multimedia
)
```

Within the main `CMakeLists.txt`, make sure the `Multimedia` package is loaded. Then add the library as a subdirectory. Finally link the library into the application.

```
find_package(Qt6 6.2 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick Multimedia)

add_subdirectory(Synth)

...

target_link_libraries(myapp
    PRIVATE
        Qt6::Quick
        SynthLibplugin
)
```

#### Notes

- Because the `Synth` library links to `Qt6::Multimedia` and the main app doesn't directly use Qt Multimedia, there's no need for the main app to link to `Qt6::Multimedia`.
- If our library had been a standard C++ library, i.e. where `qt_add_library()` includes the source files and there is no `qt_add_qml_module()`, then `myapp` would link to `SynthLib`. However because we're linking to a QML module, the Qt magic generates a QML plugin and we have to link to that instead, i.e. `SynthLibplugin`.
- If Qt Multimedia headers were included only in `Synthesizer.cpp`, then `SynthLib` could have a `PRIVATE` link to `Qt6::Multimedia`. However if we have included Qt Multimedia headers in the `.h` (e.g. `#include <QtMultimedia/QAudioFormat>`) then it has to be a `PUBLIC` link because the header file may be included in other files, meaning those files need to be able to link to Qt Multimedia. I've shown this latter case above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ideal solution to that issue, AFAIK... but there are solutions.

On most systems, you can ignore unresolved symbols using compiler options (it can be useful when building a shared library, such as a QML plugin, where the symbols will be resolved later when building the executable). With gcc it looks like:

```
add_link_options(-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all)
```

This is however not available on all systems. It seems like this isn't an option when building for Windows (see [Cygwin g++ --unresolved-symbols=ignore-all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49799217/cygwin-g-unresolved-symbols-ignore-all)).

For that case, you have another solution, which consists in using [link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_libraries.html):

```
link_libraries(Qt6::Multimedia)

qt_add_qml_module(Synth
  URI Synth
  VERSION 1.0
  SOURCES Synthesizer.h Synthesizer.cpp
)

...
```

The downside is that `link_libraries` applies for all the targets within the current directory or sub-directories... so you might've to restructure your makefiles. But it does the trick.